# Lubuntu 15.04 live (with 6gb persistent) don't boot after installing Intel and nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers

Before I intall them everything was normal. Now pc stuck at blue lubuntu boot screen.

I am using 8 gb USB drive to boot

My hdd died that's why I'm using USB drive to boot my pc (hdd unplugged)

Intel dual processor 2.0 ghz
Nvidia 8400gs
2 gb ram

Answer (score 0):

I might need some more info, but here is what I know on how to fix this:
During the boot logo, press ctrl + alt + f1 and login with your user name (UNIX user name, not the greeter user name) and run `sudo apt-get purge <insert driver package name here>`. This should clear the drivers and fix the computer.

Comment: I don't know package name. I intalled drivers from additional drivers so everything was simple

Comment: Then uninstall the additional drivers package. If you don't know what the package name is, sorry, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!! There is no possibility to install updates and drivers on live systems. I installed full system on my USB drive and I am using fully updated system with drivers